# Must Selector method be in the same instances as where the observer is?

Tags: ios, swift, callback, selector

Normally, the code `addObserver` both the `Selector method tag with @Objc` are coded in the same instance (instantiated class).

It is possible to pass a `Selector` from different instance to the `addObserver`?

The reason for doing this is because `Selector` behavior as a callback most of the time. Some of the callback methods are commonly used and could well be coded into a `CommonCallBack` Class, an example of usage would be like this:

```
class SomeViewController{

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...

    let common = CommonCallback()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
      self, 
      selector: #selector(common.methodA), 
      name: "notificationName", 
      object: nil
    )

  }

}

class CommonCallback{

  @Objc func methodA() { 
    // doing A 
  }

}
```

The issue is I keep getting `unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this by doing this way

```
class SomeViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let common = CommonCallback()
        common.enableObserver = true
    }

}

class CommonCallback{
    var enableObserver : Bool!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if enableObserver {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(common.methodA),
                name: "notificationName",
                object: nil
            )
        }
    }
    @objc func methodA() {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks clearer for the purpose of encapsulation. My implemented was very similar to this. Instead of using `viewDidLoad()`, I put that into the `constructor` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I found out, where went wrong if the code. The `observer` argument must be in the same class as the `Selector method`, so instead of:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  self, 
  selector: #selector(common.methodA), 
  name: "notificationName", 
  object: nil
)
```

it should be:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
  common, 
  selector: #selector(common.methodA), 
  name: "notificationName", 
  object: nil
)
```

This will call `CommonCallback.methodA` instead of `SomeViewController.methodA`